# Syntax to import a d3 module using webpack

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack, import

I am trying to import and use a d3 module. My project uses webpack.

The function in the module (https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/hive/hive.js) is declared like this:

```
d3.hive.link = function() {
```

I read the following to try and get the import working: https://www.giacomodebidda.com/how-to-import-d3-plugins-with-webpack/ but I can't seem to crack the correct syntax to both import and call the link function.

Some of the variations I have tried are:

```
import {link as hiveLink} from 'd3-hive';
import {hive as hiveLink} from 'd3-hive';
import * as hiveLink from 'd3-hive';
```

Can someone point me at the correct import syntax?

Comment: Are you using version 3 or 4 of  d3 library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you want to import is not an ES6 module. It is not compatible with D3 v4 (see [README.md](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins#d3-plugins)). So it just modifies your global `d3` variable. While the article you referenced is about D3 v4 it does not work that way.

I think it is ok to import d3 library (version 3) which will initialize your global `d3`:

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

and after that import that plugin which will add `hive` object into d3:

```js
import 'd3-hive';
```